# Opengl viewport in that doesn't occupy the whole window?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

I want to build and editor, similar to many 3d editors out there, that has an opengl viewport somewhere in the window, and the rest of the window contains Windows controls. How do I do that? So far I managed to create a window that opengl renders to all of its area.

Comment: You managed to create an OpenGL window in Windows API, and that's not the easiest thing in the world, so I assumed the question wasn't "How do I call glViewPort", since that's much easier. Correct?

Comment: That wasn't my question. (you already answered it :p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is better to avoid rendering to the OpenGL window except via OpenGL, the controls are child windows in their own right, so there should be no problem simply rendering to *part* of the parent window ([glViewPort](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) can help with that). Windows will take care of drawing the controls "on top of" the parent window. Alternatively, you can create a child window of your own and attach the OpenGL context to the child window. Then you can render to the whole of the child window.

Comment: I know that Blendr renders entirely in OpenGL with no Windows controls. Otherwise, nope. (In my opinion, the second alternative seems neater, but the first will be ever-so-slightly more efficient, as extra windows aren't completely free.)

Comment: I know that UnrealEngine has a single window it renders all its controls onto. So I think most big 3D engines / editiors use a single D3D or OpenGL surface and render their own widgets onto that. That said, there should be nothing wrong with creating a editor using traditional controls and mix in some opengl child windows.

Comment: @ChrisBecke you mean all those neat themed controls aren't "real" win32 controls, but more like opengl objects?